# Open webbrowser with python script executed by php

Tags: php, python

I want to open a specific url with a python script which is activated by php. When I run the python script itself with cmd it works fine but when I execute the python script with php on a WAMPserver it does not open the webpage. Anyone know about this issue?

php

```
    <?php
    $result = exec("C:/Python27/python openpage.py");
    echo $result;
    ?>
```

python

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com', new=1, autoraise=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You know PHP is server side?
This means you can call this php script of course in any browser, but it won't open the page there.
Instead it might open this page on your webserver.

If you run php in command line, it makes more sense, but there's still the question why you want it this way then.

Comment: opening the webpage is part of a longer python script used for google authentication. For example somebody has to click a php button to authenticate with their google account. The button activates the python script and should open up a new tab with the authentication page.

Comment: You can do the authentication this way, but PHP is still server side any any scripts executed through php will execute on your Webserver. So to forward you need something like header('Location: '.$url); in php which won't open in a new tab or html or js to forward.

Comment: Google for how to open links in new tabs via js or html. I don't know of any way to open a link in a new tab directly with php.

Answer (score 0):

it will not open webpage. if you want open new webpage look for jQuery or JS. you can put JS code with php and it will open webpage in browser.